# SQL column name structure for optimum search performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have code that processes GPS coordinates long / lat values and reverse geo-codes them to determine their physical street location of each set of coordinates using a geo-location API.

Once the location has been determined, the information — eg street no, street name, suburb etc etc — is stored in a locations table.

My question relates to what is the best way to structure the long / lat values in order to perform the optimum search performance.

The idea is that each time a new pair of long / lat values are received the system first searches the locations table for a record with matching values. If present the system skips the geo-location process and the system uses the record id of the record with matched long / lat value which contains the location details columns. If a matching record is not found then the system processes the geo-location code and then inserts the location details into the locations table as a new record. This way there will never be more than 1 record stored in the locations table that have the same set of long / lat

What is the best structure for storing the long / lat and column types given the need to be searching table for the existence of a matching long / lat?

#### Option 1

Have a nvarchar column called coordinates with the value like "-27.215421854 / 153.21545748" and then search for the matched string of the new long / lat values against the existing values in the coordinates column.

In this instance I perform a simple SQL query using the new coordinates to search the coordinates column in the table to find if there is a matching record.

or

#### Option 2

Am I best to have a separate long and lat columns rather than combining both values into the coordinates column?

In this instance I perform an SQL query using the new coordinates to search both the long and lat columns (where long like '[new lon val]' and lat like '[new lat val]') in the table to find if there is a matching record.

The objective is to find the most efficient database column structure in order for the database to perform the searches in the most efficient way.

Comment: Is it likely that you'll find a matching value when the values are being kept to 9 decimal places?  That's precise to about 1/10 of a millimeter.  I suggest that more likely you'll want to search for a match within some distance of a known point, say, 5 or 10 meters.  That will be a lot simpler if you use numeric values.   I understand that more recent versions of SQL Server have built in types for storing geographic locations.  If you use such a type, the built-in functions may help in the future.

Comment: thanks i will work through your comments and explore the option

Comment: so are u suggesting i keep the lon and lat values separately ??

Comment: Either store them as separate float values, or store them together in a geography type value.  Imagine that you may want to find all locations within, say, 10 meters of a given location.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ever going to need the latitude or longitude separately (and you probably will), then you should use two columns.  In fact, unless there's a built-in type that uses the composite string format, you will be better off with the two columns.

Composite columns are almost always bad news.  A column that contains a comma-separated list of values that must be searched on later becomes a disaster.

Comment: hi given the nature of geo location and mapping there will be few if any instances where we would be needing to use the long or lat value in issolation with needing to reference the other value, the composite value woyld only ever contain 3 values " 'long' ',' 'lat' "

Comment: If you would never need to format the latitude and longitude separately then maybe you're OK with a single column. If it were my design, I would not munge the two values into a single field unless the DBMS supported a built-in or user-defined type to handle geo-location. All else apart, it will be a lot harder for the user to violate the constraints on the column values if they're two separate numerical columns with appropriate numerical range constraints than if you have a string field.